# 'dzdo: service: command not found' when starting a service via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat

In my gitlab script I'm trying to install and start a java application remotely. The installation part goes fine but when I'm trying to start the service using this command:

```
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST "sudo service my-service start"
```

I get the next error:

```
dzdo: service: command not found
```

All the previous commands with sudo rights are executed successfully. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: Were you able to find solution to this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `bash` to the command solved the issue:

```
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST "sudo bash service my-service start"
```